# Haskell functions not equivalent (but they are?)

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, list-comprehension, quickcheck

I have a piece of Haskell code which capitalises words appropriately. For example, it will take "rObOT" and change it to "Robot". One function is list comprehension, the other is recursive. Both seem to work exactly the same (according to all values I have passed through them) but despite this quickCheck claims that they are not equivalent and that they are falsifiable after 1 test.

```
-- List-comprehension version
capitalise :: String -> String
capitalise xs = toUpper (head xs): [toLower x | x <- tail xs]

-- Recursive version
capitalFuncRec :: String -> String
capitalFuncRec [] = []
capitalFuncRec (x:xs) = toLower(x) : capitalFuncRec xs

capitaliseRec :: String -> String
capitaliseRec [] = []
capitaliseRec (x:xs) = (toUpper x) : capitalFuncRec xs

-- Mutual test ---
prop_capitalise :: String -> Bool
prop_capitalise xs = capitaliseRec xs == capitalise xs
```

Comment: Try both on an empty list.

Comment: Ok, that seems to have fixed it, thanks. I just added a line prior to capitalise xs saying: "capitalise [] = []"